# Arbitrary precision arthimetic in Fortran

Tags: fortran, arbitrary-precision

How can I do arbitrary precision arithmetic in Fortran?

I need two things. I want to work with really big integer and real numbers, and to work with arbitrary precise real numbers.

Comment: Try http://crd.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/mpfun90.tar.gz

Comment: http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/ (mentioned already) or http://myweb.lmu.edu/dmsmith/fmlib.html. I've used and can recommend both.