# How to print variables using FMZM high precision fortran

Tags: fortran, arbitrary-precision, fmzm

I would like to use FM package capabilities for the study of a problem in number theory.
I installed the package, compiled libraries, and ran the two test suites supplied, all without any problems.

I wrote `test.f`:

```
   use fmzm

   TYPE (IM), SAVE :: n

   n = 0
   WRITE(*,*) n

   end
```

and compiled using

```
gfortran -c -O3 -Wall test.f
gfortran fmsave.o fm.o fmzm90.o test.o -o test
```

which returned no error or warning. But got disappointed by discovering the output:

```
./test
200000
```

The number 200000 appears to be a memory location for the variable n. I experimented a little, and if I change n to complex `type (ZM)` it outputs `200000, 199999`. Similarly if I declare and initialize two variable instead of one.

If I change `TYPE (IM), SAVE :: n` to `INTEGER n`, and compile exactly as above, I get the expected `0` as output.

If I replace the code by

```
   n = 0
   do
   n=n+1
   if (n < 10) WRITE(*,*) n
   end do
```

then the output `200000` repeats 9 times and then stops. So it is the `WRITE` function which only finds the location and not the value. `PRINT` does the same.

Comment: What is the type `im`? As someone not familiar with FMZM I'd have no reason to expect the behaviour of the program to be identical to one where `n` is declared an integer.

Comment: Does FMZM support and use user-defined  derived type input/output? Or what is it supposed to print?

Comment: Please see the example code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801846/how-do-i-do-big-integers-in-fortran You will see that you should first get a string using `IM_format( 'i200', n )` and print this string.

Comment: Because `IM` is a derived type, it isn't obvious what `=`, `<`, `write` do. `n=0` may or may not set a component of `n` to `0`, and `write(*,*) n` may or may not print a component of `n`. It's entirely likely that if `IM` has a component it is merely a reference to another data structure (which is the arbitrary arithmetic part). Unless the type has user defined output, that component which is printed is indeed a "memory reference". (This is just to say, from the detail you provide it is impossible to answer the question without fine knowledge of the particular package.)

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you, that seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

As Vladimir points out, unless you write out a value of a standard type, it seems you have to first convert to a string using a maneuver such as

```
str = im_format('i100', n)
str = adjustl(str)
str = trim(str)
print*, str
```

where the middle two lines can be left out.